# Is there a charm/spell in an official Exalted2e material that allows self-multiplication?

Tags: exalted, exalted-2e

Building a character for Exalted 2ed game. Decided to start from the concept and find suitable mechanics for it, rather than choosing a splat/caste and than looking for what is available.

The concept is of a cat-themed exalted, whose 'he has nine lives' claim is actually true in the sense that he can have nine bodies at the same time.

Found a couple instance of 'homebrew' on the matter:

[Lunar Knack: Army of Self](http://rathess.xi.co.nz/exalted/index.php/Knacks:Army_of_Self)

> This knack allows the Lunar to splinter off human shapes instead of animal ones. This increases the cost to 7m per human splintered off. He can, in essence, create a small army of men and equip them if he so chooses. He can also use the same form for each one if he wants.

[Solar Charm: Manifold Army of Self](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?178280-Everywhere-at-once-Exalted&s=eff0319f6d2c89cedb08a9bc8dc1ca7c)

> The Solar is her own army, needing no mortal soldiers to change the world with her power. This Charm creates a unit of duplicates of the Solar with Magnitude equal to her (Essence-5). These duplicates are identical to the Solar in all respects, save that they have Essence 1. These duplicates rely on the Lawgiver's direct presence and power for their existence, and hence dissolve if they leave the unit.

But I'd like to know if there was any official sources that could allow this mechanically in the books I currently don't have.

Briefly checked what limited Exalted library I have:

- Exalted: Second Edition
- The Manual of Exalted Power: The Lunars
- Manual of Exalted Power - The Alchemicals
- The Scroll of the Monk

But given the amount of books that I can't check until I acquire them, on Sorcery alone, I am sure there must be something there. But than again, people wouldn't have to 'homebrew' it if there was.

Anyway, looking for the official published material, can always fall-back to the available 'homebrew' on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Glories of the Most High: Luna** (p34) there is "ANT AND STARFISH TRICK", which can create doubles (but you got to allocate some of your permanent essence - and you need to be Essence 7.). That is as close as any rule gets to that concept. Those doubles are fractions of your Lunar, and they can use charms.